# How to Control Windows GUI Applications with Python in the background?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automation

I'm currently working on a project, where I have to control a GUI Application on Windows, similar to AutoIT but its running in the background / minimized.
It has to click and type in certain places, no screenshots or Text Recognition necessary.
I have done similar things automating Android Apps running in an Emulator like Bluestacks using Android Developer Bridge, but I am struggling automating Windows Apps.

Is there something that I could use (some python module would be ideal)?

I already tried pywinauto, but because of the nature(?) of the application, i can't get something like an id to click certain buttons.

Comment: Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/
Does this fit your needs?